# Gtk.Entry unable to set_text from another method

Tags: gtk3, vala

Pretty new to vala and Gtk.
I am unable to call Gtk.Entry's set_text method, to set text from another method. Here is the sample code which I tried. I am able to set_text while in the activate() method, but just not from the tryThis() method.

```
using Gtk;
public class MyApplication : Gtk.Application {

public MyApplication () {
    Object(application_id: "testing.my.application",
    flags: ApplicationFlags.FLAGS_NONE);
}

protected override void activate () {

    Gtk.ApplicationWindow window = new Gtk.ApplicationWindow (this);
    window.set_default_size (800, 600);
    window.window_position = WindowPosition.CENTER;
    window.set_border_width(10);

    Gtk.HeaderBar headerbar = new Gtk.HeaderBar();
    headerbar.show_close_button = true;
    headerbar.title = "Window";
    window.set_titlebar(headerbar);

    //Entry is initialized here
    Gtk.Entry entry = new Gtk.Entry();
    entry.set_text ("Before button click");

    //Button is initialized and connect to method
    Gtk.Button but = new Gtk.Button.with_label("Click me");
    but.clicked.connect(tryThis);

    Gtk.Box vbox = new Gtk.Box(Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, 0);
    vbox.pack_start(entry, false, false, 10);
    vbox.pack_start(but, false, false, 20);

    window.add(vbox);
    window.show_all ();
}

private void tryThis() {
    Gtk.Entry entry = new Gtk.Entry();
    //This is not working!!
    entry.set_text ("After button click");
    message("%s -", "I am here");
}

public static int main (string[] args) {
    MyApplication app = new MyApplication ();
    return app.run (args);
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is a problem of scope. So `activate` creates an `entry` within the scope of that method, not the whole class. `tryThis` creates a new instance of `Gtk.Entry` and assigns it to a variable `entry` in the scope of that method, not the whole class.

This example fixes your problem, but is not the best solution, as discussed after the example:

```
using Gtk;

public class MyApplication : Gtk.Application {

  Gtk.Entry entry;

  public MyApplication () {
    Object(application_id: "testing.my.application",
    flags: ApplicationFlags.FLAGS_NONE);
  }

  protected override void activate () {

  Gtk.ApplicationWindow window = new Gtk.ApplicationWindow (this);
  window.set_default_size (800, 600);
  window.window_position = WindowPosition.CENTER;
  window.set_border_width(10);

  Gtk.HeaderBar headerbar = new Gtk.HeaderBar();
  headerbar.show_close_button = true;
  headerbar.title = "Window";
  window.set_titlebar(headerbar);

  //Entry is initialized here
  entry = new Gtk.Entry();
  entry.set_text ("Before button click");

  //Button is initialized and connect to method
  Gtk.Button but = new Gtk.Button.with_label("Click me");
  but.clicked.connect(tryThis);

  Gtk.Box vbox = new Gtk.Box(Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, 0);
  vbox.pack_start(entry, false, false, 10);
  vbox.pack_start(but, false, false, 20);

  window.add(vbox);
  window.show_all ();
  }

  private void tryThis() {
    entry.set_text ("After button click");
    message("%s -", "I am here");
  }

  public static int main (string[] args) {
    MyApplication app = new MyApplication ();
    return app.run (args);
  }
}
```

You should notice that:

- `entry` is brought in to the scope of the whole class with `Gtk.Entry entry;` at the beginning of the class definition
- `entry = new Gtk.Entry ();` has been removed from `tryThis` because the entry has already been instantiated when `activate` is called

This works, but for the longer term it is better to separate the window from the application. So use `activate` to instantiate a new `MainApplicationWindow` for example. Also Vala includes code generation routines for Gtk templates. This allows you to define the window and its child widgets using XML or the GUI tool [Glade](https://glade.gnome.org/) and then attach the Vala code with the Vala attributes `[GtkTemplate]`, `[GtkChild]` and `[GtkCallback]`.

Comment: Nice job! I knew what the problem was, but couldn't figure out how to fix it in Vala. I was trying `but.clicked.connect(tryThis, entry);` to pass the entry object to the callback but that wasn't working.

Comment: Perfect! That was very well explained. Thank you!